# How can I get UITextField origin y position relative to UIScreen?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have many `UITextFields` in `UITableViewCell(xib)`.

`UITableView` is also has many `UITableViewCell(xib)` all different styles.

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var fieldOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fieldTwo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fieldThree: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var fieldFour: UITextField!
.
.
.
@IBOutlet weak var fieldTwelve: UITextField!

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //how to get Origin Y position relative to UIScreen or UITableView/UIViewController?


    }
}
```

How can I get `UITextField` origin y position relative to `UIScreen` or `UITableView/UIViewController` in `UITableViewCell` swift?

Comment: can you share the screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `func convert(_ point: CGPoint, to view: UIView?) -> CGPoint` method of UIView. `UITextField` is of course a subclass for `UIView`.

To convert the origin point (0, 0) relative to the window, pass nil:

```
textField.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: nil)
```

Relative to TableView:

```
textField.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
```

You can add a method in your cell. You can call this method in your table view and passing the table view as a parameter.

```
func convertTextFieldOriginToView(_ view: UIView) -> CGPoint {
    return textField.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: view)
}
```

Comment: Thanks But I can't access tableView in CustomTableViewCell.swift without using the delegate. I want to calculate origin y without using the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to get relative position wrt `UITableView`.

```
let pointInTable = textField.superview?.convert(textField.frame.origin, to: self.table)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to access tableView in CustomTableViewCell.swift without delegate? How to access self.table in CustomTableViewCell.swift?

Comment: you can try in the CustomTableViewCell as self.superview !